# What might be the reasons that federal tax refund has been being processed for more than two months?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I overpaid my tax for 2016, and filed federal tax return on April 20 this year, but haven't received my refund yet. The online status is still being processed. Is it normal to take that long? What might be the reasons that  federal tax refund has been being processed for more than two months? Thanks.

Comment: Have you called them for more information? Typically delays are a matter of weeks, not months.

Comment: Thanks. I called 800-829-1954 which I found at https://www.irs.gov/uac/checking-the-status-of-your-refund. It is an automated system, giving the same information as their online status checking tool. I don't know how to reach a person who can access my case.

Comment: Here's a list of local taxpayer advocates for each state: https://www.irs.gov/advocate/local-taxpayer-advocate  They should be able to help.

Comment: Actually, first I'd call the IRS, 1-800-829-1040, don't choose the first option about refund, that kicks you to the automated one you're familiar with, instead choose the 'personal income tax' option, the guide here looks right for navigating to an agent: https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/2647542-i-know-the-irs-phone-number-is-800-829-1040-but-how-to-do-you-get-someone-to-actually-answer-the-line